# Is it possible use an animated.gif with kivy canvas object?

Tags: python-3.x, animation, canvas, kivy, animated-gif

I tried to use animated.gif or animated.zip for pong ball but it doesn't work,
is it possible to use animated.gif (or animated.zip) for canvas object?

```
 https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html

<PongBall>:
    size : 50,50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos : self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'animated.gif'
            #source: 'animated.zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the image sequence directly. But you can use textures to update your canvas.

```
class PongGame(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
            ellipse = Ellipse(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
        img = Image(source='animated.zip', anim_delay=1/20)
        img.bind(texture=lambda *args: self.update_texture(ellipse, img))

    def update_texture(self, ellipse, img):
        ellipse.texture = img.texture
```